# For every integer $n>1$ , does there exist a diagonal matrix $D \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $AD=DA $ holds only if $A$ is diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that for every integer  $n>1$ , there exist a diagonal matrix $D \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ and $AD=DA \implies A$ is also a diagonal matrix ?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$**Hint**

Prove and use the following lemma

> Let $D$ be a matrix, $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $D$, and 
>   $$V_{\lambda} = \Set{ v : D v = \lambda v}$$
>   the corresponding eigenspace. If $A D = DA$, then 
>   $$
> A V_{\lambda} \subseteq V_{\lambda}.
> $$

Comment: Ok, I can easily prove that lemma , but how do I use it here ?

Comment: Take $D$ to have **distinct** values on the main diagonal. What are the eigenvalues and the eigenspaces of $D$ then?

Comment: the eigen values of $D$ are then just the diagonal entries of $D$ and for each eigenvalue the eigen-space is the span of one of the standard basis vectors ...

Comment: And then by the Lemma any matrix $A$ that commutes with $D$ has to send each of these eigenspaces to itself. Which means, $A$ is itself diagonal.

Comment: I don't get that why then $A$ has to be diagonal ..

Comment: Because it sends each basis vector into a multiple of it.